# publishing paid apps on google play

Tags: android

I am an australian android developer. I have purchased a google play account with a payment of $25 using my Australia credit card. Now I am able to publish free apps but not paid apps. Also I have google checkout account with same email id giving my friend's US address and phone no., but I am unable to link my google checkout and google play account. Also when I searched for a solution to this problem they say go to "edit profile" on developer console and "setup a merchant checkout account" which is not visible in the edit profile section.

Comment: Have you signed up for checkout.google.com ? That is a prerequisite for a merchant account.

Comment: yes I have signed up for checkout.google.com.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question but should be directed to google support.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your country was not listed in [this list](http://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=150324) the time you purchased your account.

Now developers from Australia can enjoy the freedom to publish paid apps. Now you should be able to see that option in developer console.

Answer (score 0):

See the image below and check the options

[image]

Click Google Wallet Merchant center in the same screen in your console.